# How can I reduce one of the pipe in the following awk statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

`ls -lrt | awk ' !/dly/ { print $NF } ' | awk ' /000001.txt.gz/ { print } '`

I want to display the file names which matches following condition:
1)Should not contain "dly" keyword.
2)Should contain "000001.txt.gz" keyword.

I used the above command. Is it possible to combine 2 pipes I used ?

Comment: Side note. Did you mean `.` or `\.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -lrt | awk ' !/dly/ && $NF~/000001.txt.gz/ { print $NF }'
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't use `awk`, but it does reduce the number of pipes.

```
find -name "*dly*" -o -name "*000001.txt.gz*" -exec basename {} \;
```

Edit: Added changes suggested by [Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zack) (for GNU `find`)

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "*dly*" -o -name "*000001.txt.gz*" -printf '%f\n'
```

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad - I occasionally forget `find` doesn't follow the "expected" associativity and precedence rules.

Comment: If you have GNU find, you can replace `-exec basename {} \;` with `-printf '%f\n'`  Also, for a precise match to the original, there should be a `-maxdepth 1` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine conditions in `awk` mostly as if they were C expressions, so

```
ls -lrt | awk '/000001\.txt\.gz/ && !/dly/ { print $NF }'
```

should work.  (Not tested at all.)  However, if you want efficiency and robustness against unusual things (such as spaces in your filenames), then you should do it this way instead:

```
ls -1rt | awk '/000001\.txt\.gz/ && !/dly/ { print }'
```

which will be reliable as long as you don't have *newlines* in your file names.  (The *only* byte values — *not* characters; the kernel is ignorant of character encoding — that cannot appear in a pathname component are 0x2F and 0x00, but you generally don't have to worry about that unless you're writing a script that has to handle *malicious* file names.) Another alternative is to reach for a more powerful language that can do `opendir`:

```
perl -le 'opendir(my $dh, ".") or die;
          print for sort grep { /00001\.txt\.gz/ && !/dly/ } readdir $dh'
```

or more concisely (but less efficiently)

```
perl -le 'print for sort grep { /00001\.txt\.gz/ && !/dly/ } glob("*")'
```

This doesn't sort the way `ls -rt` does, though.  I don't remember how you do that in Perl.

Comment: I guess it could fail if the file name had spaces. Or if file name is `000001ptxt1gz`. Or if the owner of the file has `dly` in its name. Perhaps `ls | awk '/000001\.txt\.gz/ && !/dly/ { print $0 }'` is more accurate.

Comment: Well, *really* the way to do this is without using `ls` at all (see edit).  Good point about the dots and the spaces, though.

Comment: I like the `perl` one. Now it deserves the **+1**